# Solving Poisson's equation without a Dirichlet boundary condition

Tags: sparse-matrix, poisson

**Some context of what I am trying to do**:

I am trying to implement a function that uses the heat method to calculate geodesic distances in a tetrahedral mesh, and I want to calculate the distances for multiple possible starting points. The final part of the heat method is to calculate a solution of $Lu = b$, where $b$ is the divergence per dual vertex area of the normalized vector field of a short time heat diffusion. The solution $u$ of this will give us the final distances from the starting point.

Technically, the correct approach would be to calculate $Lu = b$ with the boundary condition of $u = 0$ at the starting point. Such a problem can be solved in a standard way. However, at least when using something like a Cholesky decomposition, this will require making a new decomposition for each different starting point. Instead of this, it would seem a lot simpler to just find some solution to $Lu = b$, and then subtract $u_0$, the value at the starting point. This makes sense because while there are multiple solutions to $Lu = b$, they all differ by a constant.

However, I'm not sure how to actually do this. With some testing, it seems the gradient descent methods generally work (even when they officially say they require a positive-definite matrix), but it seems like Cholesky decomposition is not guaranteed to succeed for $L$, due to the non-empty kernel of $L$ ($L$ is positive semidefinite, not positive definite).

**My question:**

What is the fastest way to find *some* solution to $Lu=b$, where $L$ is the Laplacian matrix, i.e. $L$ is a positive-semidefinite matrix, not a positive-definite matrix, and Cholesky decomposition (which seems the fastest by far) might not work?

It seems a bit ridiculous, but one solution I can think of is to simply choose any single point and add a Dirichlet boundary condition to it - then we can use Cholesky decomposition.

Comment: You should formulate your boundary value problem explicitly. If you're solving the Laplace equation on a domain with boundary then you must specify boundary conditions on it. If you have a domain without boundary (it is toroidal-like) then you should specify that. You can solve the problem without any Dirichlet conditions with CG provided that the problem is consistent - i.e. $\int f = 0$. Also there are ways to make rank 1 updates to Cholesky decompositions. I am still not sure what you are trying to achieve though or why are using Cholesky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this will require making a new decomposition for each different starting point

Not true? You could just offset the first solution you got using a random single Dirichlet boundary condition just as easily as you could offset any other solution.

If one just needs to pin a solution w.r.t a constant, just adding a value to any diagonal position of $L$ (equivalent to connecting a "spring" to a node connected to the surrounding) which removes this constant offset mode making the system positive definite.

---

Adding a diagonal entry $k$ has the physical interpretation of adding $F = k(u - T)$, like a spring relative to the surrounding temperature $T$, producing a load $F$.
This type of technique is sometimes employed to imitate a Dirichlet B.C by choosing a very large $k$, effectively forcing $u \approx T$.
(this technique is not advised since it destroys the messed up the conditioning of the system)

If you actually have such a "spring" in your system, you would assemble $k$ into $L$ and also $k*T$ into your RHS, but since you don't actually care about the absolute temperature here, we can just pick $T=0$.

---

Using iterative solvers it likely won't be any problems finding a solution. If i recall correctly `gmres` will give you a unique solution that $u$ where the norm $|u|$ is minimized (couldn't find a good source for this yet).

---

Proof. We have
$$
L \cdot \boldsymbol{1} = 0\\
$$
and
$$
(k\boldsymbol e_1 \otimes \boldsymbol e_1) \cdot \boldsymbol{1}c = c \boldsymbol e_1
$$
therefore
$$
\tilde L = L + (k\boldsymbol e_1 \otimes \boldsymbol e_1)\\
\tilde L \cdot \boldsymbol{1}c = c\boldsymbol e_1 = 0 \implies c = 0
$$

Comment: Right, that's the approach I describe at the end of the question - just add an extra boundary condition for any vertex. But it seems like it adds unnecessary complexity, as you would then have to adjust the right hand side of the equation for every different $b$.

Comment: Yes, I've tried and found issues with certain artificially made Laplacian matrices, Cholesky decomposition failed. with for example $-2$ on diagonal and $1$ off diagonal, in Eigen, for a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: I didn't think of just adding a value to a diagonal element, that sounds like exactly what I was looking for. If I add e.g. $1$ to the top left diagonal element of $A$, to acquire $\tilde{A}$, could you explain why the solution of $\tilde{A}x=b$ lies in space of solutions $Ax=b$? Looks to me that with such an approach you will need to adjust the right hand side if you want the solution to be same up to a constant as the solution of $Ax=b$, making it equivalent to adding some random boundary condition.

Comment: Ignore the iterative solver part, i misread your question and thought you said iterative methods did *not* work, but you correctly stated the opposite.

I added some motivation for the "spring" constant. I would recommend choosing $k = A(1,1)$ rather than just $1$ to have the correct units.

Comment: But I don't know what you mean by "adjust the right hand side". There wouldn't be anything needed except for dropping the first element from $b$.

I recommend comparing methods (Dirichlet, spring, gmres) and verifying the solutions at least once (if for no other reason than to verify you haven't made any catastrophic bugs). If you are doing many RHS for the same $L$, then the factorization seems like the right choice.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get it. For simplicity, assume the homogeneous case - we're looking for a solution of $Ax = 0$, i.e. an element in $\langle (1,1,...,1) \rangle$. Suppose we find a solution $\tilde{x}$ to $(A+\delta)x = 0$, where $\delta$ is $1$ in the top left element and $0$ elsewhere. Then we get $A\tilde{x} = -(\tilde{x}_1,0,...0)$. How do we modify $\tilde{x}$ so that we recover some solution that lies in $\langle (1,1,...,1) \rangle$ ?

Comment: Thinking about it some more - since we can show $A+\delta$ is positive definite, we know that the unique solution is exactly $0$, and thus we get that $A\tilde{x} = -(\tilde{x}_1, 0, ..., 0) = 0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't want to bother you any more, but I don't get it, and I don't get what you've proven. If you ever have the time and are willing, I would really appreciate a proof of $(L + ke_1 \otimes e_1)x = b \implies Lx = b$, under the assumption that $Lx = b$ has some solution.

Comment: I've added an answer attempt of explaining the approach you've described, is this what you had in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt at an expansion on the approach of adding a diagonal factor as described by Mikael Öhman.

Suppose $L$ is the Laplacian of some connected mesh, and we wish to find some solution of the equation $Lx = b$. Suppose such a solution exists, and denote it by $x^*$.

Let $\tilde{L} = L + e_1\otimes e_1$, where $e_1 \otimes e_1$ denotes the matrix that is $1$ at the $(1,1)$ position and $0$ everywhere else. We will prove that if $\tilde{L}x = (0, b_2, ..., b_n)$, then $Lx = Lx^*$.

We have
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{L}x = Lx + e_1 \otimes e_1x = (0,b_2, ... ,b_n) \implies Lx = (-x_1, b_2, ..., b_n)
\end{equation*}

and thus $L(x^* - x) = (b_1 + x_1, 0, ..., 0)$. Since the matrix $L$ is symmetric, it can be diagonalized with respect to some orthonormal basis, and so the image of $L$ is the orthogonal complement of $\text{Ker}(L) = \langle (1,...,1) \rangle$ (alternatively, see direct proof below). Since $\langle e_1, (1,...,1) \rangle \neq 0$, it follows that $b_1 + x_1 = 0$. Thus it must be the case that $L(x^* - x) = 0$.

---

Direct proof that the image and kernel of a symmetric matrix are orthogonal: let $u \in \text{Ker}(L)$ and take some element $Lv$ in the image of $L$. Then $u^T(Lv) = v^T(Lu) = v^T0 = 0$.